# "ENOENT: No such file or directory" in hadoop while executing WordCount program

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

Trying on the wordcount example by using command "hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.3.jar wordcount /input /output" in linux shell, however it keep reminds me that "ENOENT: No such file or directory".

I have checked for million times that the hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.1.3.jar file exists, /input also exists, just can't understand why it keeps reporting error.

[image: My hadoop directory]
[image: My command and the error it reports]
[image: The directory can also be viewed on hadoop web server with no problem]

Comment: I think the error is referring to the `file:/tmp/hadoop` local filesystem on your nodemanagers, not hdfs paths

Comment: Thank you sir. And any suggestions of how to correct that?

Comment: By writing simple directory view sentence "hadoop fs -ls /" I reckon it is actually referring to hdfs paths, as it lists all folders I have on hdfs.

Comment: I think I find where the problem is but still don't know how to solve it. It reminds " mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop/mapred/staging/huyuepeng0328208050161/.staging/job_local208050161_0001". I guess it actually tends to clean up files in this folder but I can't find this folder huyuepeng0328208050161. I guess this is what it actually means by "No such file or directory"